# Use LINQ to SQL to generate SQL based on in-memory list

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-sql, ef-code-first

POCOs

```
public class Widget
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    // other properties...
    public Guid WidgetTypeId { get; set; }
    public WidgetType WidgetType { get; set; }
}

public class WidgetType
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Widget> Widgets { get; set; }
}
```

Context

```
public class WidgetContext : DbContext
{
    // ...
    public DbSet<WidgetType> WidgetTypes { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Widget> Widgets { get; set; }
    // ...
}
```

Business model:

```
public class WidgetSearchModel
{
    public List<WidgetTypeListItem> SelectedWidgetTypes { get; set; } 

    // ... constructors... one that fills out the selection list and gets passed to a view

    public List<Widget> GetWidgets()
    {
        using (var context = new WidgetContext())
        {
            var widgets =
                (from d in context.Widgets
                 join t in SelectedWidgetTypes on d.WidgetTypeId equals t.Id
                 where t.Selected
                 // other search criteria
                 select d).ToList();

            return widgets;
        }
    }
}

public class WidgetTypeListItem
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool Selected { get; set; }
}
```

The intent is to allow the user to select multiple widget types for a search operation and have all widgets with the selected types returned to the view.

I would like the GetWidgets method to work, but obviously it won't because Linq to SQL knows nothing
about my in-memory selection list.  In the old days, I would have manually generated the SQL by walking through the selection list.  Is there a way to get Linq to SQL generate some nice SQL in this situation? Sure I could pull in all the widgets and then select based on the selection list, but that could be really inefficient depending on the size of the table.  I'd rather the logic get converted to SQL for me. Any ideas how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just select widget type ids and check if widget type id is in that list (that will generate SQL IN operator):

```
using (var context = new WidgetContext())
{
    var selectedTypeIds = from t in SelectedWidgetTypes
                          where t.Selected
                          select t.Id;

    var widgets = from d in context.Widgets
                  where selectedTypeIds.Contains(d.WidgetTypeId)                 
                        // other search criteria
                  select d;

    return widgets.ToList();
}
```

Comment: Why didn't I think of that?  :) So LINQ to SQL understands Contains to be an IN clause.  Awesome.  Thanks.

Comment: @JamesR. exactly, just keep in mind - you should use collection of primitive types when you are checking Contains (i.e. integers, guids, strings) - EF will not be able to translate complex types Contains into SQL

Answer (score 2):

You can still use the [Contains](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2009/03/26/tip-8-writing-where-in-style-queries-using-linq-to-entities.aspx) method of an in memory list:

```
var idsToGet = SelectedWidgetTypes.Select(t=>t.Id).ToList();
var widgets =
            (from d in context.Widgets
             where idsToGet.Contains(d.WidgetTypeId)
             // other search criteria
             select d).ToList();
```

This will generate something like:

```
WHERE WidgetTypeId IN (1, 2, 3..)
```